# RODBC Insert Query

Tags: mysql, r

This is my first attempt to throw data back and forth between a local MySQL database and R.  That said, I have a table created in the database and want to insert data into it.  Currently, it is a blank table (created with MySQL Query Browser) and has a PK set.

I am using the RODBC package (RMySQL gives me errors) and prefer to stick with this library.

How should I go about inserting the data from a data frame into this table?  Is there a quick solution or do I need to:

1. Create a new temp table from my dataframe
2. Insert the data
3. Drop the temp table

With separate commands?  Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Personally, I prefer the RMySQL package. The errors that you are referring to are likely to do with your version of libmySQL.dll (You have to use the one from 5.0 if you're on Windows). I guess it just feels more natural to me to use SQL to call from an SQL database.

Comment: I also use RMySQL and find it easy to use and send sql queries in native sql syntax instead of having different functions and arguments for each type of query as found in the example given by Dirk. I would be interested to know the advantages of RODBC over RMySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `help(sqlSave)` in the package documentation; the example shows

```
channel <- odbcConnect("test")  
sqlSave(channel, USArrests, rownames = "state", addPK=TRUE)   
sqlFetch(channel, "USArrests", rownames = "state") # get the lot
foo <- cbind(state=row.names(USArrests), USArrests)[1:3, c(1,3)]  
foo[1,2] <- 222   
sqlUpdate(channel, foo, "USArrests")   
sqlFetch(channel, "USArrests", rownames = "state", max = 5)  
sqlDrop(channel, "USArrests")  
close(channel)
```

which hopefully should be enough to get you going.